# keyTyped() is working in the Processing GUI but not in the browser

Tags: processing

I have a problem with my program I was working on. It would work just fine when I ran it using the Processing GUI, but for some reason it won't work when I add it to a webpage with processing.js. My problem is that keyTyped() will never be called. I have tried messing around with it, but the only thing that remotely worked was adding this to draw():

```
if(keyPressed) {
  <code to add key to string>
}
```

However, this barely even works, let alone well. There has to be a better way. This is my entire program:

```
String[] chat = new String[0];
boolean loggedIn = false;
String username = "";
String query = "";
int t = 0;
String timeStamp() {
  String hr, mn, se;
  if (hour() < 10) {
    hr = "0" + hour();
  } else {
    hr = hour() + "";
  }
  if (minute() < 10) {
    mn = "0" + minute();
  } else {
    mn = minute() + "";
  }
  if (second() < 10) {
    se = "0" + second();
  } else {
    se = second() + "";
  }
  return "[" + hr + ":" + mn + ":" + se + " ";
}
void addLocalMessage(String msg, String file) {
  if (!file.equals("")) {
    String[] file_temp = append(loadStrings(file), timeStamp() + msg);
    saveStrings(file, file_temp);
  } else {
    String[] chat_temp = append(chat, timeStamp() + msg);
    chat = chat_temp;
  }
}
void addGlobalMessage(String msg) {
  String[] users = loadStrings("users.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    addLocalMessage(msg, users[i].split(" ")[0] + ".txt");
  }
}
void attempt(String q) {
  if (!q.substring(0, min(1, q.length())).equals(".")) {
    if (loggedIn) {
      if (q.length() > 0) {
        addGlobalMessage("CHAT] " + username + ": " + q);
      } else {
        addLocalMessage("ERROR] Message length must be greater than 0.", username + ".txt");
      }
    } else {
      addLocalMessage("ERROR] Access denied.", "");
    }
  } else if (q.substring(0, min(6, q.length())).equals(".login")) {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      String[] users = loadStrings("users.txt");
      String[][] UPCombos = new String[users.length][2];
      for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        UPCombos[i][0] = split(users[i], " ")[0];
        UPCombos[i][1] = split(users[i], " ")[1];
      }
      String[] withArgs = q.split(" ");
      if (withArgs.length == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if (UPCombos[i][0].equals(withArgs[1]) && UPCombos[i][1].equals(withArgs[2])) {
            loggedIn = true;
            username = withArgs[1];
            addLocalMessage("SERVER] Logged in successfully as " + username, username + ".txt");
          }
        } 
        if (!loggedIn) {
          addLocalMessage("ERROR] Password is invalid.", "");
        }
      } else {
        addLocalMessage("ERROR] Arguments count is incorrect. Please enter as: .login <username> <password>.", "");
      }
    } else {
      addLocalMessage("ERROR] You are already logged in.", username + ".txt");
    }
  } else {
    addLocalMessage("ERROR] Not supported", "");
  }
}
void setup() {
  size(1200, 600);
  chat = new String[0];
  frameRate(10);
  addLocalMessage("SERVER] Running MSG123 v0.0.9", "");
  addLocalMessage("ERROR] You are not logged in. Please log in with .login <username> <password>.", "");
}
void draw() {
  if(keyPressed) {
    addLocalMessage("You typed something", "");
    if(key == ENTER) {
      attempt(query);
      query = "";
    } else if(key == BACKSPACE) {
      query = query.substring(0, max(0, query.length() - 1));
    } else {
      query += key;
    }
  }
  background(127, 127, 255);
  textSize(10);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  if (loggedIn) {
    chat = loadStrings(username + ".txt");
  }
  if (chat.length < 40) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chat.length; i++) {
      text(chat[i], 5, i*15 + 15);
    }
  } else {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = chat.length - 39; i < chat.length; i++) {
      text(chat[i], 5, pos*15 + 15);
      pos++;
    }
  }
  text(query, 5, 595);
}
void keyTyped() {
  if(key == ENTER) {
    attempt(query);
    query = "";
  } else if(key == BACKSPACE) {
    query = query.substring(0, max(0, query.length() - 1));
  } else {
    query = query + key;
  }
}
```

I'm hoping that someone can help me out. I don't code things for processingjs all that much, so I don't really know what I'm doing :P mag***i<strike>c</strike>***

Comment: have you tested keyPressed() or keyReleased()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a lot of care if you want to do key handling (see http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#nochartype). In this case, for the enter check, you probably want to do:

```
if (int(key) == 13) {
  ...
}
```

with a similar approach for the backspace (or any other key you're testing). There are certain technical limitations that prevent JS and Java from doing exactly the same thing, and the above link will explain all of them.

In addition, Pjs *cannot* do variables and functions with the same name (due to how JavaScript works, see http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#variablenamingcare) so for `keyPressed` Pjs offers the event handling function, but not the same-named boolean.

A simple way around this is to just use your own:

```
boolean flipScreen = false;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);
  // no need to waste cpu cycles:
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(flipScreen? 255 : 0);
  // gets retriggered based on user events
}

void keyPressed() {
  flipScreen= true;
  redraw();
}

void keyReleased() {
  flipScreen= false;
  redraw();
}
```

This also has the benefit of naming your variables after what you actually use them for, which is a near universal convention in programming.

Comment: 'keyTyped()' isn't even being called in the first place. I tested this using several functions that I know work in that method. This is driving me nuts...

Comment: If you put a `println()` or something in it, you should see it print; it exists and technically works fine, but specifically for `keyPressed` you run into http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#variablenamingcare - I've added a bit more code to show how to get around that in this case.

Comment: `keyTyped()` just isn't being called. I tried putting a `println(String)` in it, but it didn't show up in the console.

Comment: that's rather curious - A quick jsbin  reveals it works as intended over at http://jsbin.com/gajohomihi/1 -- which version of Pjs is being used for your sketch?

Comment: I don't know what version I'm using, but I do know that I can go and download the latest one and see if that helps...

Comment: Well, that was weird. It started working. (I know I should have tried that.) What was really weird though was that I had only downloaded that several months ago and the latest release was a year ago... Now it's working :) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, shoot. Turns out I still have a problem. I'm using Google Chrome and when I hit backspace it will ignore the sketch and go to the previous website. (I sorta doubt that there is much to do about this)

Comment: that's how browsers work. If you don't want it to respond to established key combinations, you'll have to write addition JS to  make that happen.

Comment: that's kind of a completely different question than the one this SO question started with, there are lots of ways to do it. Manually intercept the key event and prevent its default behaviour, using a key trap library, using a jQuery plugin, etc. etc?